# Xamarin forms - How do I set font for toolbaritems

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a toolbar in my mainpage and would like to set the font for each toolbaritem (so I can set custom fonts or normal fonts). So far I have been trying to get this done by implementing my own effect and this code works for labels but not for toolbaritems.

Whenever I run this code the effects gets added to the toolbaritem, but the effect code in android doesn't get called.

Does anyone know why I am unable to set fonts for toolbaritems with effects?

GitHub: https://github.com/jashan07/CustomEffectTest

**Edit:**
Brad Dixon suggested using TitleView which allows me to place labels in my navigationbar. As mentioned before the effect works for every control except toolbaritems. 
This is a workaround which works for now (don't know about the limits or effects this will have) but I am still wondering why this isn't working for toolbaritems.
(**TitleView was introduced in Xamarin.Forms V3.2**)

**My effect class:**

```
public static class ChangeFontEffect
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty FontProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached("Font",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ChangeToolbarFontEffect),
            null, propertyChanged: OnFontChanged);


        private static void OnFontChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if(bindable is Label labelControl)
            {
                if (!labelControl.Effects.Any((e) => e is ChangeToolbarFontEffect))
                    labelControl.Effects.Add(new ChangeToolbarFontEffect());


            }
            else if(bindable is ToolbarItem toolbarItem)
            {
                if (bindable is ToolbarItem)
                    if (!toolbarItem.Effects.Any((e) => e is ChangeToolbarFontEffect))
                        toolbarItem.Effects.Add(new ChangeToolbarFontEffect());
            }
            return;
        }

        public static string GetFont(BindableObject view)
        {
            return (string)view.GetValue(FontProperty);
        }

        public static void SetFont(BindableObject view, string value)
        {
            view.SetValue(FontProperty, value);
        }

        class ChangeToolbarFontEffect : RoutingEffect
        {
            public ChangeToolbarFontEffect() : base("CustomEffectTest.ChangeToolbarFontEffect") { }
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:CustomEffectTest.Effects"
             x:Class="CustomEffectTest.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="normal text"></ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem Text="ﭗ" effects:ChangeFontEffect.Font="materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf"></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

**Android**

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("bottomNavTest")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(ChangeToolbarFontEffect), "ChangeToolbarFontEffect")]
namespace bottomNavTest.Droid
{
    public class ChangeToolbarFontEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        TextView control;
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            try
            {
                control = Control as TextView;
                Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.ApplicationContext.Assets, ChangeFontEffect.GetTextFont(Element));
                control.Typeface = font;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.PropertyName == ChangeFontEffect.TextFontProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                var val = ChangeFontEffect.GetTextFont(Element);
                if (val != null)
                {
                    Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.ApplicationContext.Assets, ChangeFontEffect.GetTextFont(Element));
                    control.Typeface = font;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe look at using a TitleView?

Comment: Would you post a demo so that we can test it for you?

Comment: @AbbyWang I uploaded the project: https://github.com/jashan07/CustomEffectTest

Comment: @BradDixon Thank you, with your solution I was able to set a label inside the TitleView and this worked, since it's not a toolbaritem. Though I am still wondering why this isn't working for toolbaritems.

Comment: The workaround of using TitleView is a good idea. Maybe this can answer your confusion:  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52656